# Android BLE ScanSettings(SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER) problem

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, foreground-service

I referred to information on the internet that SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER scans for 0.5 seconds and then pauses for 4.5 seconds (Scan window=0.5 seconds, Scan interval=5 seconds).

---

Problem:
I have encountered an issue with the BLE Scan mode in my program where the time interval between each Scan window varies between 8 to 12 seconds (sometimes up to 20 seconds).

In addition, there is an issue when running my program on Android 10 or higher versions. When the program is running in the foreground, SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER will not work properly (the scanning will become very fast).

Noted: My "Advertise mode" is set to "low latency mode"(Advertising interval=100ms).

Thanks

---

The following section is my code:

Scan code:

```
public class Service_Scan extends Service {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public Service_Scan() {
        Log.e(TAG,"Service_Scan start");

        startScanning();


        stopScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopScanning();
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
        startScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e(TAG,"start scanning");
                startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                startScanning();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void startScanning() {

        byte[] data_all = new byte[ManufacturerData_size];
        System.arraycopy(id_byte, 0, data_all, 1, id_byte.length);


        byte[] data_mask = new byte[] {0x00,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};



        ScanFilter Mau_filter_extended = new ScanFilter.Builder().setManufacturerData(0xffff,test.getBytes()).build();


        ScanFilter Mau_filter_legacy = new ScanFilter.Builder().setManufacturerData(0xffff,data_all,data_mask).build();

        ScanFilter name_filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName("1").build();
        ArrayList<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(Mau_filter_extended);
        filters.add(Mau_filter_legacy);
        filters.add(name_filter);


        ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                .build();

        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, leScanCallback);
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        Log.e(TAG,"stopping scanning");

        peripheralTextView.append("Stopped Scanning");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I think that your information is not correct (reference?). [SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER) does not imply a dedicated timing and can therefore vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, from device to device and from software version to software version.

Comment: The following is the reference:
https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library.

Comment: Indeed, I did not see any relevant information on the Android developer website.

Comment: I think that the Nordic Semiconductor documentation probably seems a bit outdated in this aspect. 
Since energy-saving operation is now more critical than ever for mobile operating systems, this certainly also has an impact on the behaviour you complain about.
In this respect, the library you use can of course try to realise its own timing, but ultimately the operating system decides what happens when.
If the issue is important to you, I would suggest to raise an issue on github.